# Generate a table with braces and tables

Tags: tables, brackets

I'm trying to get a LaTeX table to look like the below. Any tips on how to implement the brackets?

[image]

I currently just know how to do basic tables, which would be a 11x10 table in this case. Any way to make it simpler so the left and right side of the table have different vertical # of cells?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) have a search for `tikzmark`, this type of thing has been done before :)

Comment: Have you looked at the capabilities of the `multirow` package, and its associated package, `bigdelim`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. If you're working with an odd number of rows that you want an entry to span over, using blank cell entries is sufficient. Otherwise, nested `tabular` (or `array` and/or the use of `\multirow`s (from the [`multirow` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow)) make things work:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Title1} & \textbf{Title2} & \textbf{Title3} & \textbf{Title4} \\
  \midrule
  \textbf{Ref1} & Val2a & Val3a $\left\{\begin{tabular}{@{\ }l@{}}
    Ref1.i \\ Ref1.ii \\ Ref1.iii
  \end{tabular}\right.$ & Val4a \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Title1} & \textbf{Title2} & \textbf{Title3} & \textbf{Title4} \\
  \midrule
  \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Ref1}} & \multirow{3}{*}{Val2a} & Ref1.i & \multirow{3}{*}{Val4a} \\
  & & Ref1.ii & \\
  & & Ref1.iii & \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```