# How can I do a table with curly braces on the side?

Tags: tables, brackets

[image]

I need to recreate this structure as seen in the image.

Comment: Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97060/generate-a-table-with-braces-and-tables?rq=1 ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Another option is to use `\tikzmark` or the `{nicematrix}` package: [Brace spanning multiple rows in a table and horizontal alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/105934/4301).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option with `nicematrix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{l}[hvlines, first-col]
\Block{2-0}{Title\\[-.5ex]1} & Question 1\\
 & Question 2\\
\Block{3-0}{Title\\[-.5ex]2} & Question 3\\
 & Question 4\\
 & Question 5\\
\Block{3-0}{Title\\[-.5ex]3} & Question 6\\
 & Question 7\\
 & Question 8
\CodeAfter
\SubMatrix\{{1-1}{2-1}.[left-xshift=2mm]
\SubMatrix\{{3-1}{5-1}.[left-xshift=2mm]
\SubMatrix\{{6-1}{8-1}.[left-xshift=2mm]
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```